# Knockout re render template with new data model on change event of dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout native templating to render a template on a page with some sample data.

The following code loads the sample data with template on a page

```
my.vm = {
   load: function () {
        $.each(my.sampleData.data.sections, function (i, p) {
             // Sample Data Loading Happens HERE
             // I wish to load different sample data on on-click 
             // event of  #sampledata dropdown menu. The template 
             // should re render without a page refresh. 
             // Sample data is stored in db, have to get that using
             // AJAX request
         });
     }
 }; // End of My.VM

 my.vm.load();
 ko.applyBindings(my.vm);
```

The following is drop-down menu, on click, the data update should happen

```
<select id="sampledata">
  <option value="637">Sample Data 1</option>
  <option value="697">Sample Data 2</option>
  <option value="646">Sample Data 3</option>
</select>
```

Response of the following code have the new data, but when i apply bindings with that data, the binding is failing

```
  $('#sampledata').on('change', function (){
       var cvid = $(this).val();

              jQuery.post(
                MyAjax.ajaxurl,
                {
                    action : 'getpost',
                    cvid : cvid

                },
                function( response ) {
                //Response now have new data
                 my.vm.load();
                           //But the apply bindings is not working for new data
                 ko.applyBindings(response); 

                  }
              );

       });
```

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219830/knockout-mapping-re-rendering-everything This is exacty i require, Trying it to make it work

Comment: Second @ebohlman, the question currently reads as a *requirement*, not a problem or a question. Please include what you've tried and be specific about where you got stuck.

Comment: Added some code, just give me an idea how to get this work for new data from ajax response

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what data you have coming back from AJAX, you should just have .observable() or .observableArray() properties on your viewModel. On return of the AJAX call just set your viewModel properties\array to the new data. All references to the observable() properties will be 'automagically' updated

By declaring your viewModel properties as observable you do not need to 'reapply' bindings.

Comment: Without ko.applyBindings(response); i get the data and it's being successfully added to the dom, But previously binded data is not removed. The new data is just appending to previously added data.  How to remove previously binded data before binding new data from server?

Comment: I'm not a KO expert but it seems it is designed to expose and make data, not methods, observable. Not seeing more of the code makes things difficult for me as well. I would suggest refactoring your code to make .load() a non VM method that returns the parsed data array. The data returned from .load() should then be assigned to a KO obseravable.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `ko.applyBindings` only once (preferably during initialization), not every time you load new data. You'll get an error if you call it more than once on the same DOM section.

Read about the `options` binding for dealing with `<select>` elements; it's a good idea to handle as much of your interaction with your user interface through Knockout itself rather than using jQuery to manually manipulate the DOM and set handlers.